Having problems with JPA of LocalDate columns and query parameters migrating from H2-2.1.214 to H2-2.2.224
I have problems to establish the SpringBoot application context to run a JUnit test.
The application context was no problem with SpringBoot 3.1 with hibernate-core-6.2.20.Final.
Now with SpringBoot 3.2 with hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final I get errors which I don't know how to resolve.
It looks like the type strictness of query parameters within the HQL has changed.
Here are the two named queries mentioned in the exception stack. The attributes dateFrom and dateTo of the entities are of type java.time.LocalDate. The point in question probably is the where clause with dateFrom/dateTo on one side of the relational operator and the parameter on the other:
String QN_GET_CONTRACT_BY_ID_AND_DATE = "ContractQuery.GET_CONTRACT_BY_ID_AND_DATE";
String GET_CONTRACT_BY_ID_AND_DATE = 
          """
          select c from ContractEntity c \
          where c.id = :pId \
          and c.dateFrom <= :pRefDate and :pRefDate <= nvl(c.dateTo, :pRefDate) \
          """;

String QN_GET_EMPLOYMENT_BY_ID_AND_TYPE_AND_DATE = "ContractQuery.GET_EMPLOYMENT_BY_ID_AND_TYPE_AND_DATE";
String GET_EMPLOYMENT_BY_ID_AND_TYPE_AND_DATE = 
          """
          select e from EmploymentEntity e \
          where e.id = :pId \
          and e.employmentType = :pEmpType \
          and e.dateFrom <= :pRefDate and :pRefDate <= nvl(e.dateTo, :pRefDate) \
          """;

Here is where the named query is used. The parameter is set with the common setter q.setParameter(String name, Object value):
...
TypedQuery<ContractEntity> q = this.em.createNamedQuery(
        ContractQuery.QN_GET_CONTRACT_BY_ID_AND_DATE, ContractEntity.class);
q.setParameter("pId", id);
q.setParameter("pRefDate", LocalDate.now());

List<ContractEntity> list = q.getResultList();
...

Here are the exceptions I got:
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2024-08-09T12:59:54.039+02:00 ERROR 804828 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.query.NamedQueryValidationException: Errors in named queries: 
  [1] Error in query named 'ContractQuery.GET_CONTRACT_BY_ID_AND_DATE': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.time.LocalDate' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
  [2] Error in query named 'ContractQuery.GET_EMPLOYMENT_BY_ID_AND_TYPE_AND_DATE': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.time.LocalDate' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:600) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:522) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:337) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:205) ~[spring-beans-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:952) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:624) ~[spring-context-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:754) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:456) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:334) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.lambda$loadContext$3(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:58) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.util.function.ThrowingSupplier.get(ThrowingSupplier.java:46) ~[spring-core-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.withHook(SpringApplication.java:1454) ~[spring-boot-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader$ContextLoaderHook.run(SpringBootContextLoader.java:553) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:137) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:108) ~[spring-boot-test-3.2.4.jar:3.2.4]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:225) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:152) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:130) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:142) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:98) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:260) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:163) ~[spring-test-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:383) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$11(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:378) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:197) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:179) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1708) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:509) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:499) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:310) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:377) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:290) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:289) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:279) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:364) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:278) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:106) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.10.2.jar:1.10.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:105) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.10.2.jar:5.10.2]
    ...
Caused by: org.hibernate.query.NamedQueryValidationException: Errors in named queries: 
  [1] Error in query named 'ContractQuery.GET_CONTRACT_BY_ID_AND_DATE': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.time.LocalDate' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
  [2] Error in query named 'ContractQuery.GET_EMPLOYMENT_BY_ID_AND_TYPE_AND_DATE': Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.time.LocalDate' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.validateNamedQueries(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:230) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryEngineImpl.validateNamedQueries(QueryEngineImpl.java:215) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryObserverForNamedQueryValidation.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverForNamedQueryValidation.java:39) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryObserverChain.sessionFactoryCreated(SessionFactoryObserverChain.java:35) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:315) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:450) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1507) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:75) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:409) ~[spring-orm-6.1.10.jar:6.1.10]
    ... 97 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.time.LocalDate' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.TypecheckUtil.assertComparable(TypecheckUtil.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.<init>(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.<init>(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.createComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2448) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2392) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$ComparisonPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6164) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2262) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6039) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2244) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5905) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1159) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:941) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1869) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:926) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1740) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:402) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.lambda$checkNamedQueries$5(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl$1.translate(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.validateNamedQueries(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        ... 106 common frames omitted
    Suppressed: org.hibernate.query.SemanticException: Cannot compare left expression of type 'java.time.LocalDate' with right expression of type 'java.lang.Object'
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.internal.TypecheckUtil.assertComparable(TypecheckUtil.java:358) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.<init>(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:48) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.sqm.tree.predicate.SqmComparisonPredicate.<init>(SqmComparisonPredicate.java:34) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.createComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2448) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2392) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitComparisonPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$ComparisonPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6164) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2262) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitAndPredicate(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$AndPredicateContext.accept(HqlParser.java:6039) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:2244) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitWhereClause(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$WhereClauseContext.accept(HqlParser.java:5905) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuery(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:1159) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:941) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitQuerySpecExpression(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$QuerySpecExpressionContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1869) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:926) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSimpleQueryGroup(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:269) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.grammars.hql.HqlParser$SimpleQueryGroupContext.accept(HqlParser.java:1740) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitSelectStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:443) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.visitStatement(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:402) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.SemanticQueryBuilder.buildSemanticModel(SemanticQueryBuilder.java:311) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.hql.internal.StandardHqlTranslator.translate(StandardHqlTranslator.java:71) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.lambda$checkNamedQueries$5(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:252) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl$1.translate(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:111) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.createHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:165) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:147) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.resolveHqlInterpretation(QueryInterpretationCacheStandardImpl.java:107) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.checkNamedQueries(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:249) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        at org.hibernate.query.internal.NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.validateNamedQueries(NamedObjectRepositoryImpl.java:219) ~[hibernate-core-6.4.4.Final.jar:6.4.4.Final]
        ... 106 common frames omitted

Has anyone faced the same problem?
How to resolve this problem?

I cannot find a nvl function in H2, only find NVL2. And the doc says “use CASE or COALESCE instead”.
